# Sending values to python script then running

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry guys, I am a php dev not a python one. This is probably very basic for someone. I want to import a python script, but send a value (id) to it for it to run. I have a 'parent' page and import one after the other scripts and run them when they return expected values. Using python 3

```
On parent script...

import script1 << give id
script 1 get the id and run a query and return values

impot script2 << send id
script 2 get the id and run a query and return v
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally pythonic way would be to import the required methods and execute those methods in your script. please refer the example below.

**script1**

```
def example_method():
   return 1
```

**script2**

```
def example_method_2():
   return 1
```

**Your script**

```
from script1 import example_method
from script2 import example_method_2

result1 = example_method()
result2 = example_method_2()
```

Comment: Nuran thank you but not solving the problem.  I need something like from script1 import example_method sendid, then on script1 def example_method(sendid): query with sendid
   return 1

Comment: I edited the orignial question to clarify

Comment: Normally if you run a python script you will not get any return value. So you need to wrap code in your script1 to fa function and then pass the value. 

By the way, can you share your script1. I would like to see that so I can provide you with a better solution.

Comment: in script 1 it starts with querying the database:  the id comes from the parent page....    cur.execute("SELECT unique_name FROM supportdata WHERE id=%s",id)
that is all it needs, does not need to return anything..

Comment: Because the paradigm is different from php to python. If you want to run such kind of script at the initialization of the current script you can use __init__.py to write your required methods. plese check this link. https://yasoob.me/2013/07/28/what-is-__init__-py/